# Resources to study superconducting quantum hardware for beginners

Tags: resource-request, superconducting-quantum-computing, hardware

I want to start studying quantum hardware, in particular I'm interested on superconducting qubit. Are there any valid resources for a beginner (notes, lecture...)? I'm an electronic engineer and I have some knowledge of quantum mechanics and quantum computation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the main resources in general, would be:

- [Krantz, Philip, et al. "A quantum engineer's guide to superconducting qubits." Applied physics reviews 6.2 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5089550) [[arXiv:1904.06560](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06560.pdf)]

I usually find the thesis to be very beginner-friendly, as they explain most things in much more detail than papers.

---

To get an overview of quantum hardware and superconductivity:

- [Rudolf Gross, Achim Marx. "Applied Superconductivity: Josephson Effect and Superconducting Electronics", Walther-Meiner-Institut, (2005).](https://www.wmi.badw.de/fileadmin/WMI/Lecturenotes/Applied_Superconductivity/AS_Chapter1.pdf)
  (*Change the chapter number in the URL to access other chapters*)

For circuits, resonances, qubit quantizations

- [[Thesis] Boehme, Thijs. "Characterisation and Optimisation of superconducting microwave resonators." (2016)](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/238574/238574.pdf)

Specific implementations of qubits - i.e., charge, flux, phase, transmon qubits:

- [[Thesis]Schuster D. "Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics." (2007)](https://rsl.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/RSL_Theses/SchusterThesis.pdf)

Two qubit gates - in theory, experimental implementation, gate errors:

- [Tripathi, Vinay, Mostafa Khezri, and Alexander N. Korotkov. "Operation and intrinsic error budget of a two-qubit cross-resonance gate." Physical Review A 100.1 (2019): 012301.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.100.012301) [[arXiv:1902.09054]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09054.pdf)

Decoherence mechanisms in qubits:

- [Paik, Hanhee, et al. "Observation of high coherence in Josephson junction qubits measured in a three-dimensional circuit QED architecture." Physical Review Letters 107.24 (2011): 240501.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.240501)[[arXiv:1105.4652]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4652.pdf)
- [Martinis, John M., and A. Megrant. "UCSB final report for the CSQ program: Review of decoherence and materials physics for superconducting qubits." arXiv preprint arXiv:1410.5793 (2014).](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5793)

For nanofabrication and packaging:

- [[Thesis]Slichter, Daniel. "Quantum Jumps and Measurement Backaction in a Superconducting Qubit" (2011)](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/6r4482rq)
- [Huang, Sihao, et al. "Microwave package design for superconducting quantum processors." PRX Quantum 2.2 (2021): 020306.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.020306)[[arXiv:2012.01438]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.01438.pdf)

For cryogenics, how dilution fridges works:

- [Principles of dilution refrigeration: A brief technology guide, Oxford Instruments](https://nanoscience.oxinst.com/assets/uploads/NanoScience/Brochures/Principles%20of%20dilution%20refrigeration_Sept15.pdf)

Particularly, for fluxonium architecture:

- [[Thesis]Nguyen, Long Bao."Towards the Fluxonium Quantum Processor." (2020)](https://doi.org/10.13016/co3i-ejdd)
- [Nguyen, Long B., et al. "Blueprint for a high-performance fluxonium quantum processor." PRX Quantum 3.3 (2022): 037001.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PRXQuantum.3.037001)[[arXiv:2201.09374]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.09374.pdf)

Weak qubit measurements and feedback:

- [[Thesis]Weber, Steven Joseph."Quantum Trajectories of a Superconducting Quit" (2014)](https://escholarship.org/content/qt0k0687ns/qt0k0687ns.pdf)

For novel qubit architectures like 0-pi, trimon, blochnium etc.

- [András Gyenis, et al. “Experimental Realization of a Protected Superconducting Circuit Derived from the $0 – π$ Qubit.” PRX Quantum, vol. 2, no. 1, 5 Mar. 2021](https://doi.org/10.1103/PRXQuantum.2.010339)[[arXiv:1910.07542]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.07542.pdf)

Comment: Do you know where can I find the first book you linked me?

Comment: @Simona99 Here is the link for [Chapter 1](https://www.wmi.badw.de/fileadmin/WMI/Lecturenotes/Applied_Superconductivity/AS_Chapter1.pdf) and [Chapter 2](https://www.wmi.badw.de/fileadmin/WMI/Lecturenotes/Applied_Superconductivity/AS_Chapter2.pdf). They are on Walther-Meißner-Institut's website. I think you can change the chapter number in the URL to access other chapters aswell.